# My computer is not booting after some files got deleted

Tags: windows-7

My computer (HP-mini Intel Atom) is not booting and showing just a blank screen.

- I want to install Ubuntu onto it. Please help me with it.
- I have the bootable USB stick ready but the main issue is that I cannot access the UEFI settings itself.

[image: screen]

Comment: This is an old 32-bit machine. Ubuntu no longer support that architecture. You may want to check AntiX but in either case you must know how to boot from external media, the installer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to boot from a USB drive, you have to start from another boot device. Most commonly this is done by pressing one of the following keys when the BIOS screen appears: <kbd>F10</kbd>, <kbd>F11</kbd>, <kbd>F12</kbd>. You could also change the boot drive order by going into your BIOS. The most used keys for this are <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>DEL</kbd>, <kbd>ESC</kbd>, and <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

This only works when doing a cold boot, so when waking from sleep, those keys will not work. If the system will not boot, keep pressing the on/off button for 20 seconds to shut the system down and force a cold boot.

Also, for your Ubuntu USB Thumb drive: take a look at the type of Inter Atom processor you have. They exist in both ARM and x86/AMD64 versions. You need to select the correct one or it will not boot.

Success!

Comment: How can I check my processor, I have no booklets, and neither the model number.

Comment: Is there any technical name for this type of installation so that I can check more on it.

Comment: @mathsisfun - check the sticker on the bottom. On that you should have some kind of identification number / code.

Comment: @Peregrino69 unfortunately there's nothing

Comment: After some online digging I suppose this is the x86

Comment: @mathsisfun Hum. The BIOS key should be F10 - if you power up and start immediately tapping that, can you get in? There you'd find the CPU info. If that doesn't work, you could try to put some distro to an USB and see if it boots - for example [ArchBang](https://archbang.org/) has a 32-bit version at [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/archbang/files/ArchBang32/). A side note - I don't remember seeing an Atom CPU with ARM architecture, only x86s.